# Get selected value from drop down selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, text, webdriver

I am new to selenium 
I want get the selected option value from drop down button after selection are made 
here  I tried with something but i did not get expected result

```
exams=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("exam"))
option1=exams.first_selected_option
print("option 1    ->   ",option1)
```

output is

`option 1    ->    <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="caa3498bece769cdcc9db1143e54c516", element="18ba0158-5c50-4d67-88e4-466bc6dacc67")>`

in java `getText()` is used to get the value. is there any similar method  available in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing the *WebElement* `option1`, you need to print the *WebElement*'s `text` attribute.

So effectively you need to replace:

```
print("option 1    ->   ",option1)
```

With:

```
print("option 1    ->   ",option1.text)
```